# Using lapply to populate NA values in data frame

Tags: r, lapply

I want to populate the NA values in a data frame with the mean of the non-NA values in the column in which the NA values lie. For example, in the data frame ab below I want to replace all the NA in column b by (5+6+7)/3 = 6 because that is the average of all the non-NA values in column b. I want to do the same for all the other columns.

```
ab<-data.frame(a=c(1,2,3,4),b=c(NA,5,6,7),c=c(4,NA,5,6),d=c(3,NA,NA,5))

  a  b  c  d
1 1 NA  4  3
2 2  5 NA NA
3 3  6  5 NA
4 4  7  6  5
```

I wrote the below to do this.

```
lapply(ab,function(b){lapply(b,function(c){c=ifelse (is.na(c)==TRUE,mean(b,na.rm=TRUE),c)})})
```

The result is

```
$a
$a[[1]]
[1] 1

$a[[2]]
[1] 2

$a[[3]]
[1] 3

$a[[4]]
[1] 4


$b
$b[[1]]
[1] 6

$b[[2]]
[1] 5

$b[[3]]
[1] 6

$b[[4]]
[1] 7


$c
$c[[1]]
[1] 4

$c[[2]]
[1] 5

$c[[3]]
[1] 5

$c[[4]]
[1] 6


$d
$d[[1]]
[1] 3

$d[[2]]
[1] 4

$d[[3]]
[1] 4

$d[[4]]
[1] 5
```

instead of

```
  a  b  c  d
1 1  6  4  3
2 2  5  5  4
3 3  6  5  4
4 4  7  6  5
```

If I do

```
as.data.frame(lapply(ab,function(b){lapply(b,function(c){c=ifelse (is.na(c)==TRUE,mean(b,na.rm=TRUE),c)})}))
```

hoping to cast the result of lapply into a data frame, I get

```
  a.1 a.2 a.3 a.4 b.6 b.5 b.6.1 b.7 c.4 c.5 c.5.1 c.6 d.3 d.4 d.4.1 d.5
1   1   2   3   4   6   5     6   7   4   5     5   6   3   4     4   5
```

What does this mean?
How do I get the desired result? I do see that the R output is another way of representing the desired result but I want the expected, conventional appearance of a data frame for the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
k<-sapply(ab,function(b){lapply(b,function(c){c=ifelse(is.na(c)==TRUE,mean(b,na.rm=TRUE),c)})})
ans<-as.data.frame(k,nrow=4,ncol=4)
```

gives

```
  a b c d
1 1 6 4 3
2 2 5 5 4
3 3 6 5 4
4 4 7 6 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `na.aggregate` from `zoo`

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
ab %>% 
     mutate(across(everything(), na.aggregate))
```

-output

```
  a b c d
1 1 6 4 3
2 2 5 5 4
3 3 6 5 4
4 4 7 6 5
```

---

Also, by default `na.aggregate` does the columnwise replacement of NA with the `mean` of those corresponding columns.  So, it can be more compact as

```
na.aggregate(ab)
  a b c d
1 1 6 4 3
2 2 5 5 4
3 3 6 5 4
4 4 7 6 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `map_if` function from `purrr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

ab %>%
  map_if(~ any(is.na(.x)), ~ replace(.x, is.na(.x), mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  bind_cols()

# A tibble: 4 x 4
      a     b     c     d
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1     6     4     3
2     2     5     5     4
3     3     6     5     4
4     4     7     6     5
```

We can also replace `replace` with `coalesce`:

```
ab %>%
  map_if(~ any(is.na(.x)), ~ coalesce(.x, mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  bind_cols()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lapply` -

```
ab[] <- lapply(ab, function(x) replace(x, is.na(x), mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)))

#  a b c d
#1 1 6 4 3
#2 2 5 5 4
#3 3 6 5 4
#4 4 7 6 5
```

Or with `dplyr` -

```
library(dplyr)

ab %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~replace(., is.na(.), mean(., na.rm = TRUE))))
```